# String is empty

Tags: java

I'm trying to validate the the field name is empty, and it is working

```
while(name.isEmpty()||!name.matches("^([A-Z*a-z]*(\\s))+[A-Z*a-z]*$"))
```

When I try to validate the field number when it is empty it is giving an error.

```
while (number.charAt(0) != '0' || number.length() < 4 || !number.matches("^[0-9]*") || number.isEmpty())

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Empty string `""` doesn't have any chars, so `charAt(0)` will throw `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: How to validate a string number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` because first thing in your

```
while (number.charAt(0) != '0' || number.length() < 4 || !number.matches("^[0-9]*") || number.isEmpty())
```

condition is `number.charAt(0)` which can throw exception if string is empty `""`. To get rid of this problem move `number.isEmpty()` before `number.charAt(0) != '0'`.

---

> This is to validate a phone number that starts with 0, and has a minimum length of 4 numbers.

Try this way

```
while (!number.matches("0[0-9]{3,}"))
```

Comment: This is to validate a phone number that starts with 0, and has a minimum length of 4 numbers.

Comment: I gave you a +1 as well. d:

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This one should work:

```
while(!number.matches("0[0-9]{3,}"))
```

Comment: I'm trying that when I click on enter on number field without write any information it ask me again to introduce the number, as it is happening in the name field.

Comment: @user Which numbers do you allow? Do you allow negative numbers?

Comment: This is to validate a phone number that starts with 0, and has a minimum length of 4 numbers.

Comment: +1 for the fastest gun :)